# No puedo ver el texto al cargar desde la base de datos

Tags: javascript, html

Puedo ver el texto al cargar al `textarea` desde la base de datos, pero no puedo ver todo el contenido.

¿Cómo podría detectar todo el contenido automáticamente para ponerle alto al `textarea`?

```
<textarea class="text" cols="23" rows="3"  name="text"></textarea>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso suena interesante y absolutamente posible. Pero, por favor añade lo que has intentado, tal cómo está, tu pregunta no se justa a los lineamientos de la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que solo con `CSS` no es posible, y obligatoriamente hay que usar `javascript`

```js
function resize(el){
  el.style.height = 0;
  el.style.height = (2 + el.scrollHeight) + "px";
}

document.querySelectorAll(".autoresize").forEach(el=>{
 resize(el);
 el.addEventListener("input", x=>resize(el));
});
```

```html
<textarea class="autoresize">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</textarea>
```

El truco es el siguiente

1. establecemos el `height = 0` con esto el alto del scroll es equivalente al alto del texto
2. Entonces volvemos a establecer el `height` a partir del alto del scroll (scrollHeight).
   Adicionalmente sumamos un pequeño "delta" que puede ir entre 1px y 5px aprox porque el scroll aparece cuando el alto del componente es igual o menor al de su contenido

Evidentemente esta función la podemos asignar que se ejecute al inicio y/o a algún otro evento como lo es `oninput`

Answer (score 0):

Una solución sería:

- Agregar el atributo `oninput()` para que cada vez que se escriba en el `texarea` llame a la función:

  ```
  <textarea class="text" cols="23" rows="2" name="text" oninput="expandir(this)"></textarea>
  ```
- La función se encarga de primero reiniciar la altura a `auto` para que se ajuste el alto del `texarea` al texto y posteriormente se establece la altura del `texarea` al valor del contenido:

  ```
  function expandir(textarea) {
    textarea.style.height = 'auto';
    textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
  ```

**En donde:**

- `scrollHeight` es el tamaño actual del `texarea`, por lo que irá cambiando de valor cada vez que se salten reglones dentro del `texarea` que sobrepasen los `row`, que son `2`, como el siguiente ejemplo:

  ```js
  function expandir(textarea) {
    console.log(textarea.scrollHeight);
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <textarea class="text" cols="23" rows="2" name="text" oninput="expandir(this)"></textarea>
  ```
- Entonces, al asignar esta altura cada vez que se escriba, el alto iría cambiando de valor a la altura correspondiente, pero hasta aquí ocurriría el siguiente problema: Debido a que está obteniendo un nuevo alto, el valor de `scrollHeight` irá cambiando y aumentando cada vez que se escriba:

  ```js
  function expandir(textarea) {
    textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <textarea class="text" cols="23" rows="2" name="text" oninput="expandir(this)"></textarea>
  ```
- Por lo que tenemos que reinicia la altura a `auto` para adaptar el alto del `texarea` al contenido que contiene antes de asignar el alto correspondiente:

  ```js
  function expandir(textarea) {
    textarea.style.height = 'auto';
    textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <textarea class="text" cols="23" rows="2" name="text" oninput="expandir(this)"></textarea>
  ```
- Pero otro problema es que incluso al escribir cada vez más, el alto del `texarea` irá aumentando sin haber completado el reglón (como se visualiza en el *snippet* anterior). Esto sucede por el desbordamiento vertical visible del `textarea`. La solución sería colocar `overflow-y: hidden;` para ocultarlo:

  ```
  .text {
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  ```

---

### Demo:

```js
function expandir(textarea) {
  textarea.style.height = 'auto';
  textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

```css
.text {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="text" cols="23" rows="2" name="text" oninput="expandir(this)"></textarea>
```